# A for loop outputs one list after each iteration. How to append each of them in its own row in a 3-column dataframe?

Tags: pandas, loops

this seemingly simple operation at point d) still eludes me after numerous attempts to do it by myself.

The for loop I use:

- a) cycles through an unknown numbers of excel files,
- b) selects 3 columns from each file,
- c) perform some string manipulations on their headers using
  conditions then
- d) outputs the 1-row extraction of the headers I
  have achieved so far to a individual list .

After n(3) iterations of a), b) and c), the for loop outputs lists such as:

```
['Col1','Col1a','Col1b'] 
['Col2','Col2a','Col2b'] 
['Col3','Col3a','Col3b']
```

I am looking to append/concatenate/merge these individual lists each in its own individual row into one dataframe that I can further manipulate.

Excepted final dataframe with index=True and header=None:

```
0, 'Col1','Col1a','Col1b' 
1, 'Col2','Col2a','Col2b' 
2, 'Col3','Col3a','Col3b'
```

I have tried many examples found in SO such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for lst in [list1, list2, list3]:
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(lst)
    df = df.append(df_temp)
print(df)
```

Thanks for the time you take reviewing this request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dataframe from the list:

```
pd.DataFrame([list1, list2, list3]).to_csv('file.csv', header=None, index=True)
```

file.csv:

```
0,Col1,Col1a,Col1b
1,Col2,Col2a,Col2b
2,Col3,Col3a,Col3b
```